# How to identify which type of inherited class the object is? JAVA

Tags: java, class, oop

Suppose i have a code in java with 5 classes:

```
class a = superclass.
class b = class that inherits a methods and have others.'''
class c = class that inherits a methods and have others.'''
class d = class that have an array (lets call "arrayA") of class a objects and other methods(like addObjectToArray).
class e = main.
```

My doubts are:

1. Is there a way to add B or C objects to arrayA maintaining all the different variables and methods of this this classes (B or C)?
2. If i want to add an B object to arrayA in the main code (calling the addObjectToArray) and then in some part of the code of main identify which of the classes the object is (if is a,b or c), or even in the d class identify it (suppose i initialized and everything is working. I'm now just operating the array) how can i do it?
3. Is there a way to call a method that only exists in b class or c class on the arrayA? How?

If i'm not clear enough, i'll post the code later. But i'm asking too for some reference to study arrays of objects and inheritance operating together.

Comment: "class c = class that inherits c methods" <- Is that a typo? A class can't extend itself.

Comment: Yes it is. it should be class that inherits a methods. i'll correct that.

Comment: A minimal and reproducible code example is better than trying to express everything in words and IMO `class a {String x;}  class b extends a { int y;}` is easier to understand.

Comment: I would suggest reading about the Liskov Substitution Principle. It is a design principle that helps in these situations.

Answer (score 2):

This is all pretty basic stuff that's covered in a lot of tutorials but I'll try to compile a short answer.

First, let's get the structure right. You have something like this, don't you?

```
class A {
}

class B extends A { 
  void someBMethod();
}

class C extends A{
}

class D {
  A[] arrayA;
}
```

So:

> Is there a way to add B or C objects to arrayA maintaining all the different variables and methods of this this classes (B or C)?

You're basically asking if you can assign an instance of B or C to `D.arrayA`? If so, yes that's possible because both extend A and thus have a "is-a A" property. They will still be B or C instances respectively (much like individual cars are still the same even if they are on a parking lot that only allows cars).

> If i want to add an B object to arrayA in the main code (calling the addObjectToArray) and then in some part of the code of main identify which of the classes the object is (if is a,b or c), or even in the d class identify it (suppose i initialized and everything is working. I'm now just operating the array) how can i do it?

You're asking how to know the type of the array elements, right? For this use `instanceof`, e.g.:

```
for(A element : arrayA) {
   if( element instanceof B ) {
     //it's a B
   } else if( element instanceof C ) {
     //it's a C
   }
}
```

> Is there a way to call a method that only exists in b class or c class on the arrayA? How?

Yes there is, you'd need to cast though, e.g. inside that `if( element instanceof B)` you'd then do something like this:

```
B casted = (B)element;
casted.someBMethod();
```

*Some notes*:

Using `instanceof` and casting often are not best way of solving things as this can be fragile (thing of trying to cast a C instance to B), tedious (you'd always have to check for the type first or think about adding an `E extends A`) etc.

So you might eventually look up a couple of principles:

- favor composition over inheritance
- program to interfaces
- use generics where appropriate

Answer (score 1):

You can put a B or C instance in an `A[]` array, and they maintain what they are, but when you retrieve them from the array, the compiler only knows them as type A, so to call members unique to B or C, you would have to cast the objects to B or C after you retrieve them. To do so safely, you would have to do an `instanceof` check first.

For example:

```
for (A item: arrayA) {
    if (item instanceof B) {
        B b = (B)item;
        // do something with b
    }
}
```

It is very often the case, however, that if you find you're having to use `instanceof` a lot, you have a design problem and your code could be simplified by making better use of polymorphism (inheritance and interfaces). This is not universally true, but is commonly true.

A common newcomer mistake is thinking that casting changes an object from one type to another. This is false. It only changes how the compiler views the object's type. If you try to cast an object to a type that it doesn't already match, you'll get a ClassCastException at run time (a crash).